# Why has my account been restricted?

Tags: support, question-answer-ban

I am not allowed to ask a question (for a couple of days) because I have "asked too many questions recently that have not been well received well by the community"... I understand why this would generally be a restriction.

However, in my case I asked a question yesterday which was the first I had asked in quite a while and it was received by the community fine as far as I'm aware. It didn't get any downvotes, remains at 0 but I don't see how a rating of 0 is a problem? I have asked 2 other questions (quite a while back): 1 of which as an overall rating of +3, the first question I ever asked received -2. But surely this just shows that I've learnt from my first question mistakes, because since that all questions have been received fine.

Is this a glitch in the system? If not, please can somebody explain why on earth I've been restricted...

Comment: Do you have any deleted questions? Your account record doesn't seem so bad. Also, please give this a read https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th . . . See if it's related.

Comment: @M.A.R.ಠ_ಠ nope. No deleted questions on chemistry stack exchange. I’m just so confused as to why this has happened. I have a good track record on my other accounts (especially music) and it just seems to be completely random.

Comment: OK, then let's just wait for a mod to look into it.

Comment: @BenHughes You have a deleted question: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/88478/calculate-relative-molecular-mass-using-the-ideal-gas-law

Comment: @Loong I don’t remember deleting a question, but even so, that must have been a long time ago so my initial query still holds. “3 recent questions that have not been received well” - I haven’t even got 3 “recent” questions...

Comment: Look at your question with 3 upvotes.  It's (largely) clear, it explains your thoughts on the matter, it's got a conceptual bent, and it's answerable.   These are the kinds of questions that are very well received by the community.  If you look at your two poor questions, they are just a copy of a homework problem into the question box with no other effort.  I think the difference is evident.

Answer (score 14):

Unfortunately, there is no real answer we can give that is not already found in the meta.SE link provided in the comments.

Diamond moderators are not privy to the internal workings of the automatic question ban; hence, we cannot tell you exactly how many downvotes how many days ago is sufficient to trigger it, or how many upvotes it would take to remove it.

You have one deleted question sitting at −3 and one existing question at −2; clearly, this seems to be enough to trigger the question ban.

[The [deleted question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/88478/calculate-relative-molecular-mass-using-the-ideal-gas-law) was not deleted by you, but rather by [another automated process](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/roomba).]

Comment: Yeah i supposed, it’s just odd and quite annoying because neither of those downvoted questions are recent in the slightest despite the message I received!!! Oh well

Comment: Is this because diamond moderators are not allowed this information, or because it's just generally unknown and no one's asked a higher-up?

Comment: @tox123 The former. [Here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/193373/312770) (amongst, I'm sure, other places), it is explicitly mentioned by a SE employee that the algorithm is kept a secret.