# How to get unblocked from asking questions?

Tags: support, question-answer-ban

I got down votes on some of my questions and some of them closed, so, I got blocked from asking. After a period of time from being blocked, I regained the privilege of asking, but only one question that I could continue asking after it if it was positively recieved.
That question got two upvotes, but, I could not ask any question after it. Also, I have many questions that are well-recieved. So, why am I banned from asking? How to remove that ban?

Answer (score 10):

I don't really want to rehash what has already been said, so here is the relevant link:

[What can I do when getting "We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th)

Please take a look there, it has all (publicly) available information there.
In particular, you may wish to note that deleted questions still influence the question ban. Out of your 21 questions, 12 are deleted. From [another answer of mine to a similar question](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4191/16683):

> Unfortunately, there is no real answer we can give that is not already found in the meta.SE link provided in the comments.
>
> Diamond moderators are not privy to the internal workings of the automatic question ban; hence, we cannot tell you exactly how many downvotes how many days ago is sufficient to trigger it, or how many upvotes it would take to remove it.

Comment: Based on my observation on other meta sites, some mods did a courtesy to provide all links to the OP's deleted questions (since posts older than 60 days can't be found anymore by OP) so that they (hopefully) could be fixed/improved. Just an idea though...

Comment: @AndrewT., I will admit that I do not pay that much attention to main meta and that I was unaware of the 60-day limit. I (or, I’m sure, any other moderator) would be happy to provide the links to deleted questions if OP would like it.